# How to handle blob field in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file, spring-batch, blob

I need to read a blob column from DB e put it in a file and vice versa with Spring Batch.
How can i do it? 
I'm using spring batch to read data from DB and put it in CSV file and vice versa but now i have to manage also blob datatype and when there is it i need to create a single file with this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it is by using **LobHandler**. You can either get your blob as Bytes and convert it to a String with (**getBlobAsBytes**), or as BinaryStream with (**getBlobAsBinaryStream**)

```
public class YourRowMapper implements RowMapper<YourObjectType> {
        @Override
        public YourObjectType mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {

            LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
            String value = new String(lobHandler.getBlobAsBytes(resultSet, "COLUMN_NAME"));

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes i know it, what i don't know is how to use blob whit spring batch.
You say to convert this blob in string and put it in a file?

Comment: Have you tried JdbcCursorItemReader as your reader providing it with the rowMapper. And for your writer FlatFileItemWriter?  What is the size of your BLOBs?

Comment: The size of single BLOB can be different MB and total size of all blob can be also over 3GB.

Comment: Ok, then  try using  getInputStream in you rowMapper and set it in your Item, And a custom writer that will write the InputStream to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use `byte[]` type field to present blob. It can depent what DB are used.